# Count occurrences of strings in Java

Tags: java, string, class, count

Is there a good class that can count the occurrences of specific strings in java? I'd like to keep a list of names and then create unique email addresses for each name. For each occurrence of a last name, I'd like to increment the associated number by one.

Ex: If I have 3 people with the last name Smith, I'd like their address to be smith1@(Address), smith2@(Address), and smith3@(Address). I saw a class "Map" but I can't seem to initialize it correctly. Is there a class that I can use to keep a list of strings and their occurrences?

Comment: Take a look at the answer to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4363061/count-number-of-occurences-from-a-text-file-using-map/4363140#4363140

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Map](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) would be a viable data structure for this, if you're just looking to count the number of emails with given last names.  The key would be a String (the last name), and the value would be an Integer (number of occurrences).

You instantiate it as follows:

```
Map<String, Integer> nameOccurrences = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
```

To add a value to the map:

```
nameOccurrences.put("Smith", 1);
```

To check if a name is in the map:

```
if (nameOccurrences.containsKey("Smith")) { ... }
```

To get a value from the map:

```
Integer occurrences = nameOccurrences.get("Smith");
```

Note that names with different capitalization would be considered different keys.  If you need to ignore capitalization, you'd have to do something like make the keys all uppercase before adding them to the Map.

Comment: Kaleb, thanks for elaborating a little bit. I think you've nailed exactly what I want to have it do.

Comment: If you go this route, you may find it cleaner to make two iterations over the data set.  First, simply put 0 into the map for each name (when the name is already there, it does no harm).  In the second pass, look up the value for the name (it is guaranteed to be there from the first pass), add one to it, and save it back to the map.  I find this cleaner than checking whether the entry exists and doing something different depending on the answer.

Answer (score 1):

[Bag](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiset) is the data structure you are looking for. [**Multiset**](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/index.html) is a Bag implementation from [google-guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) library.

Comment: Seems a bit overkill for the poster - given he/she doesn't know what a HashMap is. Just my 2 cents, though.

Comment: Both of these won't help because they only count the occurrences but don't actually save multiple items.

Comment: I disagree. A simple utility function takes care of producing the email addresses, given the Map/Bag. You really can't expect a built in data structure to do that, surely.

Comment: @cHao perhaps, but that can't be a good idea. There's not really a way that can help.

Comment: Yes Mike, I'm a java noob, and I think I'll go with HashMap. It looks like all I'll need after glancing at the API. Appreciate the input from all :)