# HashMap as a static member in java

Tags: java, hashmap, static-members

I want to carry a HashMap over as a static member for each instance of a new class. Every time I try to .get or.put into my HashMap, however, I get a NullPointerException. Help!?

I'm doing: `public class EmailAccount {
private static HashMap<String,Integer> name_list;` and then `name_list.put(last_name, occurences);` Even `name_list.containsKey(last_name);` returns NullPointer.

This comes from an earlier question: [Count occurrences of strings in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4776229/count-occurrences-of-strings-in-java)

Comment: ObComment: Mutable statics are generally a very bad idea.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to instantiate it.

```
private static Map<String, Integer> name_list = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
```

#### See also:

- [Java tutorial - Creating objects](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/objectcreation.html)
- [Java collections tutorial - The Map interface](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/map.html)

---

Note that using "list" in variable name of a map is confusing. Don't you want it to be a `name_map` or `name_occurences`? That underscore does by the way also not really fit in [Java naming conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html#367), but that aside.

Comment: I learned C++ first and am just picking up java. I'll see what I can do with this advice, thanks for the quick response! Lemme ask this though, doesn't putting "new" end up making a new HashMap for each instance? That's exactly what I don't want!

Comment: No, it doesn't since you declared it `static`. The same map will be shared among all instances of the same class. The `static` modifier makes it a class member. If you remove it, then it will becomes an instance member and indeed a new one will be created for each instance of the class. See also [Java tutorial - Understanding instance and class members](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html).

Comment: @V1rtua1An0ma1y since it is static, it will only create one instance of a HashMap for the class, not one for each instance of EmailAccount.

Comment: Much thanks from this java noob. As always, I appreciate the feedback :)

Answer (score 5):

You still need to initialize it, like

```
private static HashMap<String, Integer> name_list = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
```

When you leave a class-level object field with no initialization -- or any object reference, for that matter, it defaults to null.

While it may seem obvious to you that you want a HashMap, so it should just implicitly initialize it, Java doesn't know if you want in fact a HashMap, or maybe a HashMap subclass, like [LinkedHashMap](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html)

Class-level *primitives*, like `int` can be left just like `private static int someNumber;` and won't throw a NullPointerException by accessing it--but that's because primitives can't be null. Java will assign it some default value (in `int`'s case, 0).

Comment: When you leave ANY object (reference) with no initialization, it defaults to null.

Comment: @dty True, but I was just emphasizing for this example. I'll change it so there is no confusion. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 2):

You didn't instantiate the list. You declared it, but didn't instantiate.

Answer (score 1):

You created a field that can hold a HashMap, but you didn't put anything inside of it

You need to put a `new HashMap<String, Integer>()` into your field.